# web scraping python for car search

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanted to look for Skoda 2018 with less than 100K KM from this site
https://www.autocenter.co.il/
however I cannot find the right method
here is what I did

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://www.autocenter.co.il/"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
#print((response.status_code))
first=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"product-wrapper-inner"})
print(first[0].text)
```

Comment: to make it easier for yourself you can directly scrap from this link :
https://www.autocenter.co.il/shop/?flr_manufacturer=196&flr_from_year=2018&flr_mileage_range=0-100000

only returns skoda, 2018, with less than 100k km.

i have a bit of experience with selenium for scraping, it is easy and well documented and gets this task perfectly done :)

Comment: having your search criteria is in the link as parameters will make it easier for you

Comment: thank you very helpful ,do you have a recommendation where to complete this knowledge -udemy ,coursera etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @Elyes construct your url based on your criteria

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://www.autocenter.co.il/shop/?flr_manufacturer=196&flr_from_year=2018&flr_mileage_range=0-100000"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
#print((response.status_code))
first=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"col-lg-11 text-center px-4 px-lg-15"})
[i.text for i in first]
```

output: